# How to make the content inside a div that's under another one accessible/clickable?

Tags: css, html, css-position, overlap

I have two divs: one that's fixed positioned on top of another which holds the content and scrolls under the first. The first (top) div has a triangular png background. When the content of the second div scrolls under the transparent area of the first div, how could I possibly make that overlapping area still accessible/clickable? You can see a clearer scheme at this link:

[image: [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP9nV.jpg)]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try using the pointer-events css option

```
#div1 {
     pointer-events:none;
}
```

example of it working here -> http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html

Comment: This will [opt-out IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), if that matters.

Comment: Work around for IE -> filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='youimagehere.png');

Comment: Legacy filter is [deprecated in IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) and [removed in IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview.aspx), so IE10 is still opt-outed...

Comment: That's nice, but consider that the black triangle will contain a menu navigation. Could it be possible to have half of div#1 clickable, and the other "transparent half" accessible for the div(#2) that's under? Sorry, I might have not made myself very clear.

Comment: Hmm, I'd think about splitting div#1 into two divs (top and bottom). Then making the bottom div have point-events:none. Does that help?

Comment: That could possibly do it! Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 0):

reduce the height of the top div. for an example around 20%. Then make the over-flow option to

`overflow: visible;`